# I have two local disks and my python external modules are being installed in the one that i don't use

Tags: python, python-module, disk

So, I have my computer and it has two diferent local disks, and I installed python3.
All the packages(later i installed other external ones like: pandas) were installed in the C: disk, and i cannot access any modules from the one that it seems like I use (G:), as my computer says
Can someone help me with this??
by the way, i am a windows 7 user

Comment: How do you know you can't access ? Probably python isn't added to path of the system. Try to import some modules and then post the error that you get

Comment: @BradFigueroa it gives me a module error: module not installed, but then i check them in C:\Users\"my name"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages and they actually exist, installed by pip, this is the moment i realized that i have another disk: G:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs, which shows that python isn't even installed